# QGIS - Connection Lines using geometry generator between 2 layers in a relation N-1

Tags: qgis, expression, array, geometry-generator

I would like to know if there is any way to generate a connecting line between 2 points layers (**blocks**-points representing a watershed, **concpoints**-points representing the concentration location of the flow from that watershed) through the *geometry generator* in the style panel of QGIS, with the specification that in some cases there is a relationship of several basins concentrated in a single point.

In these specific cases, the attribute *"ID_UC"* that indicates which basins contribute to a concentration point is a string that separates the basin ID's (*"ID_QE"* attribute of the layer blocks) using a comma, as in the following image:

[image]

As you can see in the following image, I was able to accomplish the task for simple cases where there is a ratio of 1 basin to 1 concentration point, using the expression

```
make_line(
   start_point($geometry),
   geometry(
       get_feature(
           'concpoints',
           'ID_UC',
           "ID_QE" 
       )
   )
)
```

[image]

I imagine that there is a way within the geometry generator to transform the string field "ID_UC" into an array, where each element would be the ID of a different basin, and thus be able to make this connection between the blocks layer and the concpoints layer, or another way to generate these connection lines.

[Download example project and layers](https://www.mediafire.com/file/44md48s0rmnelcg/ConnectingLinesGG.rar/file)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using `array_foreach()` function

collect_geometries(array_foreach(string_to_array( "ID_UC" ),

Use this expression on the 'concpoints' layer.

```
collect_geometries(array_foreach(string_to_array( "ID_UC" ),
make_line(
    start_point($geometry),
    geometry(
        get_feature(
                   'blocks',
            'ID_QE',
            @element
        )
    )
)))
```

[image]

Comment: That was exactly the result I was hoping for, I was approaching the problem using the geometry generator from the blocks layer, but the important thing was the end result.

Thank you very much.